# Insert a view using JS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to insert a view using javascript?

I wish to perform an ajax call, get the data, then insert a view in to a page and provide the data from the ajax call to that view?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the render method on a view. Like so;

```
$view = View::make('your.view')->render();
```

And then return the html (which is the output) from your controller method by returning the data stored in $view.

If you need to add any data to the view just add the second parameter to the view make.

Comment: So in my controller I would I would make and return $view to the ajax call? Then in JS insert the HTML in to the page?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can do this,
set the route for pages you want to call.

e.g.,

```
Route::get('callajax','PagesController@showAjax');
```

and then in PagesController@showAjax you return the view. 
e.g.,

```
public function showAjax() 
{ 
return View::make('ajaxpages'); 
}
```

and then in ajax call you code this

```
$.ajax({
url:'callajax',
});
```